How do I change the time zone in Anylogic?
How can I disable Daylight Saving Time ?
In my model, the DST is automatic but I don't want it. I figured how to bypass it for the events (using toTimeoutInCalendar( DAY, 1 )) but I have a couple of schedules in relative times and when the DTS occurs, it moves enverything by 1h.
I thought of maybe changing my timezone but couldn't find anywhere how to do it or if it is even possible.

In your simulation experiment properties, look for the advanced java section, in there you will see on Java Machine Arguments you can put
-Duser.timezone=Asia/Qatar

This will use for that simulation experiment, the timezone of qatar, which is a country that has never used daylight savings in all history.

You can also call TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Country/City")); in the experiment setup code, same thing
